# Getting text from a file in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have made a script that makes a file with custom text in, but soon i need to be able to take text FROM THE TEXT FILE I MADE TO THE BATCH SCRIPT. Like being able to ECHO the text in the file in the batch script. If you don't understand what i mean, just ask me in the answer/comment stuff and i'll answer you with more info.

(I'm a beginner so that's why i can't do it myself.)

Comment: can we see your code plz

Comment: start with `set /p line=<file.txt`. (see also `set /?`) Come back, if you have a specific problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using " type FILENAME"?
(I don't got enough reputation to comment, so it goes here:)

Text file 'test.txt' contains:

> foobarbaz

Opening a CMD in the same folder as this text file and doing:

> type test.txt

will output

> foobarbaz

into the CMD window on it's own line, might depend on the OS you're on, but you should be able to google search for type(.exe)

(I tested on Win 8.1)

You should also be able to stream this output where you want, based on your needs.